# How can I evaluate this surface integral

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Find the value of Surface Integral $ \displaystyle \int \int yzdxdy + xzdydz + xydxdz$ Where the surface is the outer side of the surface formed by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =4 $ and the plane $x = 0 , y= 0 ,z = 0$ and  $z=  2$

Now I would like to solve this surface integral with the help of Gauss Divergence theorem, but firstly I want the surface integral in the form $\int F.n ds$

so that I can calculate $\nabla. F$

Can anyone tell me how should I solve this integral ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This is a surface integral of the second kind. A surface integral of the form

$$\iint_R Pdydz + Qdxdz + Rdxdy$$
$$= \iint_S (Pcos\alpha + Qcos\beta + Rcos\gamma)dS$$

Where

$$cos\alpha = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}$$
$$cos\beta = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}$$
$$cos\gamma = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}$$

Where
$$A = \frac{\partial{(y, z)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}$$
$$B = \frac{\partial{(z, x)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}$$
$$C = \frac{\partial{(x, y)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}$$

Based on these formulae we use the following parameter for the cylinder
$$x = 2cos\theta $$
$$y = 2sin\theta $$
$$z = z$$

Using the above formulae we have 
$$\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2} = 2$$
Where
$$A = 2cos\theta$$
$$B = 2sin\theta $$
$$C = 0$$
Substitute x, y, z into the integral we have
$$I = \iint_S (2zsin\theta cos\theta + 2zcos\theta sin \theta)dS$$

Using the change of variables from x, y, z to $\theta$ and z, J factor is 2.

$$= \int_0^{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 4z sin \theta cos \theta d\theta dz= 4$$